# Program will not sum the key mapped values of the dictionary called L within the for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Program will not sum the key mapped values of the dictionary called L within the for loop

```
y = int(input("please enter the current year: "))
I = str(input("Please enter your statement of intent: "))
L = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'h':8, 'i':9, 'j':1, 'k':2, 'l':3, 'm':4, 'n':5, 'o':6, 'p':7, 'q':8, 'r':9, 's':1, 't':2, 'u':3, 'v':4, 'w':5, 'x':6, 'y':7, 'z':8} # Pythagorean Gematric System

def sum(x, L):
    R = 0
    for i in x:
        R = R + L[i]
    if R > 9:
        return (R % 9)
    elif R <= 9:
        return R

def Y(x, y):
    return (y + (4+x))

S = sum(I, L)
print("The right year for your intention is: "+str(Y(S, y)))
```

The error:

```
please enter the current year: 2020
Please enter your statement of intent: i win
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in sum
KeyError: ' '

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 2):

The input value `i win` has a space in it, and there is no matching key in the dictionary. Either add another key, value pair to `L`, or catch non-existing keys in the function:

```
def sum(x, L):
    R = 0
    for i in x:
        try: 
            R = R + L[i]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    if R > 9:
        return (R % 9)
    elif R <= 9:
        return R
```

Result:

```
please enter the current year: 2020
Please enter your statement of intent: i win
The right year for your intention is: 2025
```